# Cannot retrieve TGT despite allowtgtsessionkey registry entry

Tags: java, windows, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

I'm trying to wire our windows client application to use a single-sign-on mechanism. I'm following the explanations that can be found [here](http://www.javaactivedirectory.com/?page_id=196). I'm already having trouble getting the first step to work, that is, acquiring the Signed On User's Ticket-Granting-Ticket. When running my unit test (code see below), I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:800)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:671)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:584)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
at org.myapp.test.cases.SSOTest.testSSO(SSOTest.java:28)
```

This happens when I run the test with Java 7. I thought this means that the ticket cache is empty. However, when I run the test with Java 6, the login is successful, and I can retrieve a fully populated `Subject` object from the `LoginContext`. As I read [here](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/07/23/java-7-jaas-and-kerberos-single-sign-on-vs-newer-windows-systems/), Java 7 now fully respects the Windows 7 policies which allow/deny exporting TGTs. So I set the the `allowtgtsessionkey` value in my registry, hoping this would fix my problem. But despite having relogged and restarted, I still can't access my TGT with Java 7. With Java 6, it works just fine. Could anyone point out what I'm missing?

SSOTest.java:

```
    @Test
    public void testSSO() {
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "D:\\login.conf");

    LoginContext lc = null;
    try {
        lc = new LoginContext("TestLoginContext1");
    } catch (LoginException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        lc.login(); // Exception happens here
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Subject signedOnUserSubject = lc.getSubject();
    System.out.println(signedOnUserSubject);
    }
```

login.conf

```
TestLoginContext1 {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useTicketCache=true doNotPrompt=true debug=true;
};
```

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.COM
[realms]
MY.DOMAIN.COM = {
    kdc = domaincontroller.my.domain.com
    admin_server = domaincontroller.my.domain.com
    default_domain = MY.DOMAIN.COM
}
```

Comment: Is you account a local machine admin?

Comment: Yes, my account is local admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is a limitation of Windows when it comes to accounts that are also in the local administration group. I read the following [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~weijun/special/krb5winguide-2/raw_files/new/kwin):

> Known Issues
>
> If an AD account is also added into local administrator group on
>   the    client PC, Microsoft restricts such client from getting the
>   session key    for tickets (even if you set the allowtgtsessionkey
>   registry key to 1).    The workaround is: Just forget you're a logged
>   in user, call kinit.exe.    Do not depends on LSA credential cache.
>
> In a recent hotfix
>   ([35]http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942219/en-us,    should be
>   included in Vista SP1), this restriction is lifted for normal
>   service tickets. However, it still applies to TGT. Since Java uses TGT
>   to acquire tickets for other services (the standard Kerberos process),
>   this update provides no benefit to JGSS programming on Windows.
>   Furthermore, even if the implementation of Java is changed to read
>   service tickets from the LSA cache, it still cannot perform
>   delegation,    since a TGT is always needed in that case.

Comment: I won't accept this answer, yet, for if anyone might have a workaround.

Comment: This *is* the answer, unfortunately. This is Microsoft. I suffer fromt his PITA too. The only option is to write a SSPI-backed JGSS implementation.

Comment: Could you give any reference/tutorial links for SSPI? I will include them in my answer.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.de/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=LZk&rls=org.mozilla%3Ade%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=sspi+jgss+provider&oq=sspi+jgss+provider&gs_l=serp.3...11006.19896.0.20605.21.20.1.0.0.0.215.2584.2j17j1.20.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..13.8.985.HMmFPp8vNZU]) you go.

Comment: Thank you for this - called kinit.exe and all works ok. Annoying, but this answer is best.

Comment: @user2482461 The kinit.exe is the one coming with the jre i suppose? 2nd, does it require providing credentials, or does it magically access the (client side) windows keytab? 3rd on what windows version?

Comment: @JimHolden If anybody still interested I just made it working. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73115983/836215