# jdbc kerberos oracle authentication issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, kerberos, ojdbc

I have been facing an issue while trying to connect to oracle using kerberos authentication.
Similar issue was reported earlier but in my case exception trace is different - 
[jdbc kerberos oracle authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416230/jdbc-kerberos-oracle-authentication)

Code is referred from oracle documentation below (connectWithDefaultUser() )
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/clntsec.htm#CIHCIDHF

The exception trace is -

    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.reset([BZ)[B
        at oracle.net.ano.AuthenticationService.a(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ano.AuthenticationService.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at oracle.net.ano.AuthenticationService.h(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ano.Ano.negotiation(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:439)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)`

I am guessing the authentication was successful but there is something missing either on server side or the kerberos setup.

I am using **jdk1.8** and **ojdbc6**

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you should use ojdbc8 if you are on Java 8.

Comment: Thanks @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, I second your suggestion, but same code works well on windows environment with same config and not on linux and that is something I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @Karthikeyan, upgrading ojdbc to version 8 resolved the issue, though I am not clear how it works on windows environment without the upgrade, If someone can shed a light on this it would be great :)

For now it works just fine.