# Java HttpURLConnection automaticlly attach authentication header when return code 401

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, jaas

I am trying to implement HTTP Kerberos authentication for my client application, after compare available solutions I decide to use JNA to fetch Kerberos ticket through Windows SSPI, and it works well if I manually attach the Kerberos ticket to each `HttpUrlConnection`:

```
req.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Negotiate " + ticket);
```

But I know that the JAAS way of Kerberos authentication does not require this manual authentication header attach step, it will automatically handle a 401 response with Negotiate scheme, and re-send the request with authentication header attached. You just send a normal `HttpUrlConnection` and don't need to worry about authentication and ticket part.

So what I am trying to implement is something like that, for a `HttpUrlConnection`, 1) handle the `401` response with `Negotiate` scheme, and 2) attach the authentication ticket from SSPI, and automatically re-send the request like JAAS do.

I kind of figured out that may be I can handle the 401 with a custom `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` and do the ticket fetch, but I still have no clue on how to attach the authentication and resend the request after that. Could anyone help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: See `java.net.Authenticator`. This is exactly what it does.

Comment: @EJP well the reason I am using the SSPI is to avoid user/password prompt, extend `java.net.Authenticator` must implement getPasswordAuthentication() method, in my case, pw is not required. And, it seems this class does not provide a interface to access request header.

Comment: AFAIK, when Java is running on Windows, and you have a proper JAAS configuration set up, and the current Windows session has Active Directory credentials available in the LSA ticket cache, and Windows does not block access to that LSA ticket cache _(depends on a flag in the registry - blocked by default on Servers, for instance)_, then JAAS is supposed to retrieve the AD credentials (a Kerberos TGT) and pass them automatically in the response header.

Comment: Oops... actually JAAS uses the cached Kerberos ticket (a TGT) to obtain a service ticket (for service `http` on server `xxx`). Anyway, see http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~weijun/special/krb5winguide-2/raw_files/new/kwin under "The Initial Credentials" for the TGT that's in the LSA cache.

Comment: Also, some limitations on the types of user accounts that can SSO > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427343/cannot-retrieve-tgt-despite-allowtgtsessionkey-registry-entry

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the suggestions. Yes I have tried the JAAS way, and I even created a working POC, but for some reason I prefer a zero-configuration solution. LSA is disabled by default on Windows, or kinit command need to be run beforehand to generate the TGT cache file (don't mention current JRE kinit does not support renewable ticket), that's why I am using SSPI solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, I haven't tried it yet, but it may work.

I refereed the [JAAS Krb5LoginModule](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.java) and Apache HttpClient [WindowsNegotiateScheme](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient-win/xref/org/apache/http/impl/auth/win/WindowsNegotiateScheme.html) implementation, and [RFC 4559](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559).

First of all implement a custom `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`, after configure this class as the default login module, it will be called whenever authenticate is required (`401`).

In the `login()` method of the custom `LoginModule` class, call `SSPI` method using JNA to get the Kerberos ticket, and set the ticket into the Subject's private credentials set, the ticket will be attached to request header when re-sending the request.

According to the RFC 4559, there may be several round-trips before the the authentication process completed, in each round-trip the server will return `401` with response header like `Negotiate xxxx` and you may need to get the response and read the header from the response, use the header to get a new ticket from `SSPI` method and set it in Subject.

If everything goes well server will return `200` eventually.

Correct me if I misunderstood anything.